# MySQL Workbench remove all foreign key constrains from all tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I was using foreign key constrains then I switches my database to multiple databases and I want to remove ALL FOREIGN KEYS constrains with one command.

### What I have tried:

I have tried to export my database then import it without any foreign keys constrains but that was a bad solution because the database is large.

Comment: Iterate over INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE in stored procedure.

Comment: @Akina please more details

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-key-column-usage-table.html

Comment: You cannot remove all fks with one sql statement (not command). You can disable fks or as @Akina suggested, you can write a stored proc.